# Django: Trouble importing updated form

Tags: python, django

learning Django for the first time and I'm getting my first error here. Saying it "cannot import 'UserRegisterForm' from 'users.forms'". I'm following a tutorial and I haven't skipped any steps. Not too sure what to try next...thanks for any suggestions.

Tutorial Video (33:15): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q4jPR-M0TAQ&t=1959s

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import UserRegisterForm

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
            return redirect('blog-home')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

---

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

---

[Folder Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oo3RI.png)

Comment: great video, but 4 years old now...

Answer (score 0):

This is weird, but I fixed it by deleting, saving, and then re-pasting this line of code into the forms file...

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

Have no idea why that fixed it...but oh well it works now